# Android Stock Browser - Bottom bar, how to detect show/hide

Tags: javascript, android, html, browser, android-4.4-kitkat

Is it possible to detect when bottom bar in stock android browser (for example raw Android 4.4.2) when this bottom bar appear / disappear? Or even disable it on my website?

I've prepared video:

http://sendvid.com/jr2ftjgt

The worst thing about it is that bar overlays website, you cannot scroll to the end of website because this bar covers it. And you have to wait for it disappearing.